# Way to make a web browser always muted by default?

Tags: web-browser, windows-10, volume-control

I use several web browsers. I'd like to dedicate just one to being muted all the time so that browser will be for when I specifically don't want to hear ad videos on websites or hear sounds from horror movie ads on youtube.

I use a windows 10 laptop. On windows 10, you can set a single app to be muted manually through volume mixer. I believe once you shut down the computer, this becomes undone.

What software can help me make an web browsing program in windows 10 stay muted even if I restart the computer?

Would be willing to pay about 10$

I'm aware you can manually mute a tab in chrome. That's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mute applications by opening Volume Mixer, the settings are saved and don't reset after restarting computer:

[image]